# LINQ query with multiple join result represented as comma seperated results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

The query below returns a list of leads joined to an "address" table, of where there can be multiple per lead.

I'm looking to return one response per lead, with addresses concatenated in the city view within the model and seperated by commas. If there are no cities in the join result, it should return '-'.

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
Company Name | Company City
===========================
Company 1    | Glasgow
Company 1    | London
Company 2    | London
Company 3    | NULL
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
===========================
Company 1    | Glasgow, London
Company 2    | London
Company 3    | -
```

**QUERY**

```
 return (from t1 in db.Opportunities
                    from s1 in db.OpportunityStatus.Where(x => x.OpportunityStatus_ID == t1.StatusReason_ID)
                    from t2 in db.Leads.Where(x => x.Lead_ID == t1.Lead_ID)
                    from t3 in db.LeadAddresses.Where(x => x.Lead_ID == t2.Lead_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from t4 in db.Addresses.Where(x => x.Address_ID == t3.Address_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby (t1.Created) descending
                    select new FieldSalesPipelineViewModel
                    {
                        Id = t1.Opportunity_ID,
                        CompanyName = t2.Company_Name,
                        OpportunityTitle = t1.Opportunity_Title,
                        CompanyCity = "",
                        OpportunityStatusName = s1.OpportunityStatus_Name
                    }).Take(howMany);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a string-join:

```
CompanyCity = string.Join(",", (from p in db.Opportunities where t2.companyname == p.companyname select p.Companycity)
```

For your example:

```
 return (from t1 in db.Opportunities
                    from s1 in db.OpportunityStatus.Where(x => x.OpportunityStatus_ID == t1.StatusReason_ID)
                    from t2 in db.Leads.Where(x => x.Lead_ID == t1.Lead_ID)
                    from t3 in db.LeadAddresses.Where(x => x.Lead_ID == t2.Lead_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()

                    orderby (t1.Created) descending
                    select new FieldSalesPipelineViewModel
                    {
                        Id = t1.Opportunity_ID,
                        CompanyName = t2.Company_Name,
                        OpportunityTitle = t1.Opportunity_Title,
                        CompanyCity = string.Join(",", (from t4 in db.Addresses Where t4.Address_ID == t3.Address_ID select t4.CompanyCity),
                        OpportunityStatusName = s1.OpportunityStatus_Name
                    }).Take(howMany);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm not sure I follow. My address data is stored in table "Addresses" - would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: This gives me the error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I'm guessing I have to execute the query before I project, but I'm not entirely sure how in this notation!